# C# - cascade of "not null" conditions

Tags: c#, optimization, multiple-conditions

I would like to ask for any tips how to improve the code in case of cascade of conditions, where you have to ask if the property inside of property is not null.

Just simple dummy example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB classB { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB
{
    public List<ClassC> classesC { get; set; }
}
public class ClassC
{
    public ClassD classD { get; set; }
}
public class ClassD
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Then let's say you want to get such a value: `classA.classB.classesC.First().classD.value;`

Is there any efficient way to do that and be sure you won't get the error, when any of these classes is null?  Instead of many conditions:

```
if (classA != null && classA.classB != null && classA.classB.classesC != null && classA.classB.classesC.First() != null && classA.classB.classesC.First().classD != null) return classA.classB.classesC.First().classD.value;
```

Just note, I'm not looking for solution to use `try` block and catch NullException.

Thanks.

Comment: elvis operator????

Comment: As @Selvin mentioned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: btw `First()` will throw when no elements... you should consider use `FirstOrDeafulat()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), `?.`

Note that you'll probably also want to use `FirstOrDefault()` rather than `First()`: `First()` will throw if the collection is empty, but `FirstOrDefault()` will return the default value (`null` in the case of reference types).

```
var result = classA?.classB?.classesC?.FirstOrDefault()?.classD?.value;
if (result != null)
{
   return result;
}
```

You can combine this with a simple [pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) to simplfy things a bit:

```
if (classA?.classB?.classesC?.FirstOrDefault()?.classD?.value is { } x)
{
    return x;
}
```

The `{ }` pattern here means "an object which isn't null".

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Use a Null Propagation operator `?` to safely access values.

```
var val = classA?.classB?.classesC?.FirstOrDefault()?.classD?.value;
```

Just to keep in mind, it will return a nullable datatype. If you're wiling to assign value to the non-nullable variable such as int, use this:

```
var val = classA?.classB?.classesC?.FirstOrDefault()?.classD?.value ?? 0;
```

You can read more [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/900017/Null-Propagation-Operator-A-New-Feature-of-Csharp)